# How can I obtain old version of access token in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

How can I obtain old version of access token in Gitlab? the one without `glpat-`in it

Answer (score 0):

This prefix is now set [by default](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/db/structure.sql?expanded=true&viewer=simple#L11188).

If you are admin, you can open a [Rails Console](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/rails_console.html#starting-a-rails-console-session) and check the current value :

```
irb(main):007:0> ApplicationSetting.current.personal_access_token_prefix
=> "glpat-"
```

You can update it like this :

```
irb(main):011:0> ApplicationSetting.update(personal_access_token_prefix: '')
```

Check again and create another Personal Access Token, the prefix should not appear.